# How to format the title in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data with a name "catch" and the observations are:

```
x  y
0.50 3.66
0.63 3.95
0.77 5.82
0.92 7.38
1.07 8.58
1.24 9.31
1.42 9.52
1.61 9.52
1.81 9.58
2.04 9.54
2.29 9.56
2.56 9.44
2.87 9.07
3.21 8.61
3.61 7.92
4.09 7.04
4.67 5.93
5.43 4.52
6.52 2.90
8.43 0.63
```

I used this code in R:

```
library(ggplot2)
ccplot <- ggplot(data = catch, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
          geom_point(shape = 19, colour = "#0072B2")

ccplot <- ccplot + geom_abline(intercept = 14.58, slope = -1.85, col = "#D55E00")

ccplot2 <- ccplot + 
           xlab("time") + 
           ylab(expression(paste("ln[C(L1, L2)]/(", Delta, "t)")))

ccplot2 + ggtitle(expression(paste("Length-Converted Catch Curve\n(for Z=1.85; M(at 23"*degree*"C)=0.69; F=1.16; E=0.63"), hjust = 0))
```

The problem arises when the printed plot have a large (distant) space between the number 23 and the degree symbol.

[image: The plot printed with the above code]

How do I format the title so that the space be gone? Or is there any other method to accomplish the proper title in ggplot2?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably better off using the unicode degree symbol rather than trying to use plotmath in this case.

```
ccplot2 + ggtitle(expression("Length-Converted Catch Curve\n(for Z=1.85; M(at 23\u00B0C)=0.69; F=1.16; E=0.63)"), hjust=0)
```

You could also use the `atop()` expression for layout

```
ccplot2 + ggtitle(expression(atop("Length-Converted Catch Curve","(for Z=1.85; M(at 23"~degree~"C)=0.69; F=1.16; E=0.63)")))
```

What's happening with your code is that it's printing the first string (with the new line), then when you switch to math mode with the degree, you exit the string and start to the right of the two-lined string.

Comment: Thank you. But I have additional question. Is the code applicable if I put the text from (for Z=...) as a subtitle?